# angular2 resolveAndCreate HTTP - missing HTTP_PROVIDERS in RC7

Tags: http, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

back in RC4 when HTTP_PROVIDERS existed I could create my custom http instance using

```
export function createHTTP(url:string, headers?:Headers){
  let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
    myHttp,
    {provide:'defaultUrl', useValue:url},
    {provide:'defaultHeaders', useValue:headers || new Headers()},
    ...HTTP_Providers
  ])
  return injector.get(myHttp)
}
```

myHttp was a wrapper for Http

```
@Injectable()
export class myHttp{
  constructor(@Inject('defaultUrl) private url:string, @Inject('defaultHeaders) private headers:Headers, private http:Http){}

  get()
  put()...
}
```

Now with HTTP_PROVIDERS deprecated and removed, how do I provide it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you create an reflector imperatively?

Comment: I'm building a library to facilitate the access to my database so that I can use something like this in my components (client-side)

this.todoDB = createHttp(url, headers)

then

this.todoDB.post....

Comment: You don't need to create your own injector for this.

Comment: is there a more elegant way to achieve this? :)

Comment: Just ask the user to import your module. If you module contains `imports: [HttpModule]` you should be fine. And add `Http` to the constructor where you need it `constructor(private http:Http) {}`

Comment: cool, but I'd still need to use ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate to create the a new myHttp object don't I, since I need to resolve the http there? Otherise if I use the new keyword, the user would need to inject http himself and pass it along each time

Comment: I don't understand why. Can't you just add this code to a service that can get `Http` injected like explained above?

Comment: Ok i totally got what you suggested now and it works just fine!! thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to hear :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  ...
})
class AppModule {}
```

or copy the definition of `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from the Angular2 source to your source and use it there like before.

```
const HTTP_PROVIDERS = [
    {provide: Http, useFactory: 
      (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions): Http =>
          new Http(xhrBackend, requestOptions), 
          deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]},
    BrowserXhr,
    {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
    {provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions},
    XHRBackend,
    {provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: () => new CookieXSRFStrategy()},
];
```

You can also create an injector yourself using these providers like

```
let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, /* this.injector (parent injector if any) */ );
var http = child.get(Http);
```

See also [Inject Http manually in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243525/inject-http-manually-in-angular-2)

Comment: does it mean as long as HttpModule is imported in the (client-side) AppModule, I don't need to "provide" HTTP_PROVIDERS anymore to inject Http? the code I'm writing is aiming to be a library

Comment: You don't need it to inject `Http` but you need it when you create an injector yourself like you do in your question.