# Inject Http in Angular 4.0.0

Tags: angular

When I try to call ajax request before bootstrap the app module. I am getting.

```
  let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        Http,
        BrowserXhr,
        {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
        {provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions},
        {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XHRBackend}
      ]);
      this._http = injector.get(Http);
```

[image: get cookie error]

Comment: This should be tagged with angular not in angularjs  i think. Also what is the error you  are getting.

Comment: @Senthil. update the screen shot with complete error message

Comment: Have you tried to create providers like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491647/angular2-resolveandcreate-http-missing-http-providers-in-rc7/39491672#39491672 ?

Comment: Please refer below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609853/angular-4-and-ionic-3-no-provider-for-http

Comment: take a look at this repo for making http calls https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the HttpModule to your application.
    import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```