# Inject service into class (not component) Angular2

Tags: class, angular, service, dependency-injection

I am struggling to find a way to inject a service into an class object in angular2.

*** NOTE: This is not a component, just a class. ***

```
export class Product {

  id: number;
  name: string;
  manufacturer: string;

  constructor(product: any) {

    this.id = product.id;
    this.name = product.name;
    this.manufacturer = product.manufacturer;

}
```

The only solution I have come up with is to pass the service reference to the constructor whenever I create a new product... ie: instead of `new Product(product)` I would do `new Product(product, productService)` . This seems tedious and error prone. I would rather import the reference from the class and not messy up the constructor.

I have tried the ReflectiveInjector:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([ProductService]);
this.productService = injector.get(ProductService);
```

However, this creates an error `No provider for Http! (ProductService -> Http) at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor]` (Also I'm pretty sure this creates a new productService when I simple want to reference my singleton that is instantiated at the app level).

If anyone knows of a working solution I would be glad to hear it. For now i will pass the reference through the constructor.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to inject a service into a plain class. Angular DI only injects into components, directives, services, and pipes - only classes where DI creates the instance, because this is when injection happens.

To get `Http` from a custom injector, you need to add to it's providers like shown in [Inject Http manually in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243525/inject-http-manually-in-angular-2/39243599#39243599)

or you pass a parent injector that provides them

```
// constructor of a class instantiated by Angulars DI
constructor(parentInjector:Injector){
  let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([ProductService]);
  this.productService = injector.get(ProductService, parentInjector);
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ReflectiveInjector-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Ya it seems like the easiest thing for me will be to push the reference through to the constructor to the class when it's created.

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with a similar issue, and what I ended up doing, was making the service a singleton as well as an Angular injectable.

This way you can inject via DI into Angular classes and call the static `getInstance()` method to get the singleton instance of the class.

Something like this:

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  static instance: MyService;

  static getInstance() {
    if (MyService.instance) {
      return MyService.instance;
    }

    MyService.instance = new MyService();
    return MyService.instance;
  }

  constructor() {
    if (!MyService.instance) {
      MyService.instance = this;
    }
    return MyService.instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because this works well in my case where I want a single service instance for my entire app. But what if I need different instances of the service in different parts of my app?

Comment: This won't help if your service depends on another components/services/modules/etc and needs to inject them in the constructor.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with except I didn't new up the service.  I throw an exception that parent hasn't injected the service.  This address Denis observation that and dependency won't be available to the service.